# How to change property on FactoryGirl association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, factory-bot

I have a couple factories where user belongs_to business:

```
  factory :user do
    business
    ...
  end


  factory :business do
    ...
  end
```

Then in my spec I create a user:

```
  before (:all) do
    @user     = create(:user)
    @business = @user.business
  end
```

But now how do I change a property on that business? I want to set:

```
@business.setup_complete = false
```

but when the application controller checks that property it's back to the original value.

Answer (score 0):

Did you do a @business.save after changing the property?